# StringTrimmerEditor on HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, string, http, parameters

I'm using Spring MVC on this.

Let's say that I have a controller for generating pdfs. The request it accepts can have multiple optional parameters. I want to make sure that any parameter passed to it is trimmed of their whitespaces.

For this, I've created a controller advice to add a StringTrimmerEditor so that any parameter can be trimmed.

ControllerAdviceClass:

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmer = new StringTrimmerEditor(false);

        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmer);
    }
```

Controller endpoint method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/createPdf")
 public ModelAndView generate(HttpServletRequest request) {  
    //Process request and generate the pdf
}
```

Sample request:

```
    http://localhost:8080/api/v1/createPdf?timezone=       +7&language=fr   &pageType=recipe&ingredients=carrots,milk,ice&name=Carrot Shake
```

In the above request, the timezone, language and pageType are required parameters.

When trying to generate the pdf, I noticed that none of the parameters I send to the endpoint have their whitespaces removed, resulting in an exception.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you write your own method for trimming and validation ? I suggest you can also do by implementing AOP

Comment: Good point. Though now I'm wondering why this solution is not working for my code. Seeing other examples using this solution, it worked for them.